# Differentiate unique_together validation error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've got a model with a `unique_together` constraint.

```
class Postit(models.Model):
    """Represents a single post-it."""
    x_axis = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('X axis'))
    y_axis = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Y axis'))
    content = models.CharField(_('Content'), max_length=140, default='')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('x_axis', 'y_axis')
```

If I use a form to create a new post-it, the constraint is checked, and in case of a conflict, the error is listed in the `non_field_errors` property. Fine.

My problem is that I want to launch a different action depending of the kind of form error. I want a specific action if there is a unique constraint error, and another action for any other kind of errors.

Given that my app will be translated in several languages, how do I know if the form is invalid because of the constraint or for another reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that you can translate the string you're comparing if you want to just check `non_field_errors`.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
if _('Some error text') in self._errors['__all__']:
    # do something
```

That's not really the most elegant solution though. Your best bet is to simply verify the `unique_together` constraint yourself in `Model.clean` or `Model.validate_unique` and respond accordingly.